# Unable to display data in polymer api

Tags: json, api, polymer, web-component

I was using polymer [example](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html) and they used core-ajax to call the api.I want to display text from the openweathermap api.When i call the api it displays no data.I'm not able to display any data and when i placed console.log(this.post) in the post-list element it gives me undefined.I'm practically a noob when it comes to polymer.

Below is the Api Calling Method

```
<polymer-element name="post-service" attributes="posts">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <core-ajax id="ajax"
      auto
      url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=hyderabad"
      on-core-response="{{postsLoaded}}"
      handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('post-service', {
    created: function() {
      this.posts = [];
    },
    postsLoaded: function() {
      // Make a copy of the loaded data
      this.posts = this.$.ajax.response;
    },
    /** 
     * Update the service with the current favorite value.
     * (Two-way data binding updates the favorite value 
     * stored locally.) If this was a real service, this
     * method would do something useful.
     * 
     * @method setFavorite
     * @param uid {Number} Unique ID for post.
     * @param isFavorite {Boolean} True if the user marked this post as a favorite.
     */
    setFavorite: function(uid, isFavorite) {
      // no service backend, just log the change
      console.log('Favorite changed: ' + uid + ", now: " + isFavorite);
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This is element is used to display

```
<polymer-element name="post-list" attributes="show">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    post-card {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    </style>

    <post-service id="service" posts="{{posts}}">
    </post-service>

    <div layout vertical center>

      <template>
        <post-card>
          <h2>{{post.weather.main}}</h2>
          <p>{{post.weather.description}}</p>
        </post-card>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({});
  console.log(this.post);
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Example json

```
[
  {
    "uid": 1,
    "text" : "Have you heard about the Web Components revolution?",
    "username" : "Eric",
    "avatar" : "../images/avatar-01.svg",
    "favorite": false
  },
  {
    "uid": 2,
    "text" : "Loving this Polymer thing.",
    "username" : "Rob",
    "avatar" : "../images/avatar-02.svg",
    "favorite": false
  }
]
```

My api response([json](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=hyderabad))

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 78.47,
        "lat": 17.38
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 802,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "scattered clouds",
            "icon": "03d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "cmc stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 303.15,
        "pressure": 1010,
        "humidity": 62,
        "temp_min": 303.15,
        "temp_max": 303.15
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.7,
        "deg": 280
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 40
    },
    "dt": 1436677800,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 7830,
        "message": 0.0124,
        "country": "IN",
        "sunrise": 1436660330,
        "sunset": 1436707470
    },
    "id": 1269843,
    "name": "Hyderabad",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [core-ajax](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-ajax.html) element sends an event when the data are received. To use them you have to manipulate the fired event.

```
postsLoaded: function(event, detail) {
  // Event contains lot of informations
  console.log(event);
  // Detail would be the received data
  console.log(detail);
  // Make a copy of the loaded data
  this.posts = detail; // or this.posts = event.detail;
}
```

It would be easier to see what happens if you add a listener on the `posts` attributes in your element *post-list*. See the [doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html) section *Observing properties*.

```
<script>
Polymer({
  postsChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  }
});
</script>
```

Moreover, I think you have a typo in your code. In the template you are using *post* and no *posts* :

```
<template>
  <post-card>
    <h2>{{post.weather.main}}</h2>
    <p>{{post.weather.description}}</p>
  </post-card>
</template>
```

Finally, if you are starting with Polymer, I suggest you to start with the version [1.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/).